# Is bsxfun really applied element-wise?

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

Suppose that I have the following function:

```
function x = printAndKeepX(x, y)
    x
    y
end
```

and I invoke `bsxfun` like so:

```
bsxfun(@printAndKeepX, 1:4, 1);
```

Were `bsxfun` really element-by-element, I would expect `printAndKeepX` to be called 4 times, with the arguments `(x, y)` being `(1, 1)`, `(2, 1)`, `(3, 1)` and `(4, 1)`, respectively. But the output shows that it is called just once with `(x, y)` being `([1 2 3 4], 1)`:

```
x =
     1     2     3     4

y =
     1
```

Why? How can I know what's considered an "element"?

**Edit:**
[The documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) suggests that sometimes the called function can receive two scalars and sometimes a vector/matrix and a scalar. Can I know for sure which of these is going to happen?

I'm interested in both the regular and GPU versions of `bsxfun`.

Comment: turns out that `printAndKeepX` won't run on GPU due to some restrictions partially listed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/execute-matlab-code-elementwise-on-a-gpu.html#bsp51uy)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) also states that:

> `fun` must also support scalar expansion, such that if `A` or `B` is a scalar, `C` is the result of applying the scalar to every element in the other input array.

In your case `B` is in fact a scalar, so your function is applied on `A` only once.

The same applies when the input arrays are matrices. For example, consider a case where `bsxfun` is invoked with a matrix `A`={ *a*<sub>ij</sub> } of size *m*×*n* and a vector `B`={ *b*<sub>ij</sub> } of size *m*×1. `B` would be replicated *n* times along the second dimension, and the function would be called as follows:

> `function([a11, ..., a1n], b1)`
>   
>   `function([a21, ..., a2n], b2)`
>   
>   `...`
>   `function([am1, ..., amn], bm)`

This results in *n* function calls for vector-scalar inputs rather then *mn* function calls for pairs of scalars. If the function is vectorized, it may be reflected in a possibly significant performance gain.

Comment: Exactly. For example `bsxfun(@printAndKeepX, 1:3, rand(3,3));` clearly does run three times, i.e. element by element.

Comment: To be exact it's `bsxfun(@printAndKeepX, rand(3,3), 1:3)`, and if it was element wise, I'd expect it to run 9 times. The question is, can I know for sure when the called function is going to get a vector and when a scalar?

Comment: No, three times. Each time your function is called receiving 1 column of each input (in this case). This is because the size of the non-singleton dimension is 3. Just to be clear this is the size of the dimension in Y that corresponds to the singleton dimension in X. Also the order doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: I've added a generalization for matrix/vector pairs.

Comment: @EitanT, I think that the `[a11, ..., a1n]`'s should be column vectors.
Is this deterministic behavior, or Matlab might decide that it wants to invoke the function more times and using scalars? My function actually depends on receiving a (column vector, scalar).

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's deterministic or not, but I'd make my function vectorized and deterministic, so that it could be applied on either vectors, columns, or scalars.

Comment: And in my example the vectors passed to the function are rows, because `B` is replicated along the _second_ dimension.