# arrayfun when each row of the array is an input

Tags: matlab

My situation is that I would like to map a scalar array `A` by a function with handle `fun` sending a row vector to a row vector, to acquire `B`, such that `B(i,:) = fun(A(i,:))`.

The most reasonable solution I could think of looks like:

```
temp = mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1)),size(A,2));
B = cell2mat(cellfun(fun,temp,'UniformOutput',0));
```

However, the conversion to cells and back seems like overkill (and is assumably computationally expensive). It is also not clear to me why cellfun complains about non-uniform output. Does a more efficient way jump to mind?

Comment: related question: [how to apply a function to every row in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2307249/1336150)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another solution that employs [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). Although not as fancy as `bsxfun`, it doesn't require declaring a helper function:

```
subs = ndgrid(1:size(A, 1));
B = accumarray(subs(:), A(:), [], @fun); %// @fun is the function handle
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without using cell arrays at all with bsxfun.

Using Marcin's example data and function:

```
A =[ 0.5669    0.4315    0.4515    0.7664    0.5923; ...
     0.8337    0.7317    0.4898    0.2535    0.7506; ...
     0.3321    0.5424    0.4585    0.8004    0.9564];

fun = @(x,y) x*2;
B= bsxfun(fun,A,1);

B =

    1.1338    0.8630    0.9030    1.5328    1.1846
    1.6674    1.4634    0.9796    0.5070    1.5012
    0.6642    1.0848    0.9170    1.6008    1.9128
```

Edit:

As Eitan noted, fun above may need to be a wrapper on your 'real' anonymous function so it would be more complete to show my solution as:

```
fun = @(x) x *2;        % Replace with actual anonymous function
fun2 = @(x,y) fun(x);   % Wrapper on fun to discard unused 2nd parameter
B= bsxfun(fun2,A,1);
```

Comment: Nice use of bsxfun, but this applys function to one value in a at the time, or to one row at the time?

Comment: @Marcin Should a scalar be passed to `bsxfun` as one of the arrays, `bsxfun` would perform scalar expansion and apply applies it to every element of the other array ([a recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18079629/1336150) deals with this issue).

Comment: @grantnz +1, but the `fun` in the question is unary. You should note that your `fun` is a wrapper function defined for being used in `bsxfun`...

Comment: @EitanT. Yes, this solution does require a simple wrapper to discard the unused 2nd argument although if the primary function is an anonymous function it could easily discard a dummy 2nd parameter.

Comment: @grantnz Easily, yes. But this should be noted, as it seems at first glance that you're feeding `bsxfun` with the original function.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but in case someone else sees this, Matlab added rowfun to the 2013b release which can evaluate rows of tables and returns a column vector. Here is an example:

```
f = @(c) sum(c.^2);

x=[1 2;
   3 4;
   5 6];

z=table2array(rowfun(f,table(x)))

z=
   5
  25
  61
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do as follows, if I understand what u want to do:

```
A = rand(3, 5);
fun = @(x) x*2;
B = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i) fun(A(i, :)), 1:size(A, 1), 'UniformOutput', false)');

% example results:
A =

    0.5669    0.4315    0.4515    0.7664    0.5923
    0.8337    0.7317    0.4898    0.2535    0.7506
    0.3321    0.5424    0.4585    0.8004    0.9564


B =

    1.1338    0.8630    0.9030    1.5328    1.1845
    1.6675    1.4635    0.9795    0.5071    1.5013
    0.6642    1.0848    0.9169    1.6008    1.9128
```

This will apply `fun` to each element of row in A. This is based on the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307249/how-to-apply-a-function-to-every-row-in-matlab/15971182#15971182). Also there u find more info and explanation what is happening or alternative ways of applying function to rows in an array.

Comment: Your implementation looks identical to mine. I'll check the other thread for more info -- still curious principally in whether transforming to cells is the most sane way to proceed.

Comment: Thanks, ran into the same problem, this seems to be the most simple way to achieve the right result.