# Matlab Check elements one at a time

Tags: matlab

I want to check words in an array one by one against a dictionary file, what would be the simplest way of doing this?

e.g.

```
word = nchoosek('london' , 3)
```

and I want to check if each of the 3 letter words produced are in a dictionary file.

e.g.

```
dictionary(word)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cell-array of words you want to check, you should use `ismember`. So, if you had a dictionary array `dict` and a set of words `words`, you would use

```
check = ismember(words,dict);
```

where `check` would be something along the lines of `[0,1,1]`, if the first word wasn't in the dictionary, but the other two were.

EDIT:

I guess that `dictionary` is a function? Sorry, I didn't pick up on that the first time around. In that which case, borrowing from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18200325/2837253) answer to a different question, you can do the following:

```
dict_fun = @(word,trash)dictionary(word);
check = bsxfun(dict_fun,nchoosek('london',3),1);
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the dictionary is a file which only accepts one word at a time, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: Is it possible to load the dictionary into a cell-array? For instance, on my linux distribution I can use `fid=fopen('/usr/share/dict/words');dict = textscan(fid,'%s');fclose(fid);` to load in a dictionary of words, and I would then be able to use that in the means that I described above.

Comment: Nope, the only way to check if a word is in the dictionary is to input them one by one with the syntax dictionary('word'). So I need to create a for loop to check each word produced with nchoosek somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that `dictionary` was a function. See my amended answer.