# Matlab: arrayfun, two matrices X,Y as components of the vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, parameter-passing

Suppose that **X**, **Y** are the matrices of coordinates inside the given intervals

```
xc = 0, yc = 0
xl = linspace(xc - 10, xc + 10, 2);
yl = linspace(yc - 10, yc + 10, 2);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xl,yl);
```

and fun is a handle to some function test(v)

```
fun = @(v)test(v);
```

How to combine both matrices **X**, **Y** so that they represent components *x,y* of the vector ***v***

```
res = arrayfun(fun, [X,Y]); //First processed X and then Y
```

Unfortunately, this solution does not work....

There is another way when the function is modified so that two parameters *x*, *y* are passed

```
fun = @(x, y)test(x, y);
res = arrayfun(fun, X, Y); //This works well
```

However, I would like to preserve an intertace of the function if any solution exists.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Redefine `fun` as `fun = @(x, y)test([x,y]);`

> No need to modify function `test()`

```
xc = 0;
yc = 0;
xl = linspace(xc - 10, xc + 10, 2);
yl = linspace(yc - 10, yc + 10, 2);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xl,yl);

% Given function test
test =@(v)v(1) + v(2);


% pass x, y as a vector  
fun = @(x, y)test([x,y]);


res = arrayfun(fun, X, Y);

% X =

   -10    10
   -10    10

% Y =

   -10   -10
    10    10

% fun(x, y) = x + y

% res =

   -20     0
     0    20
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Matlab doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

`B = arrayfun(func,A)` applies the function `func` to the elements of `A`, one element at a time

`B = arrayfun(func,A1,...,An)` applies `func` to the elements of the arrays `A1,...,An`, so that `B(i) = func(A1(i),...,An(i))`

So you are using `arrayfun` in the wrong way.

Use a for loop or two nested loops instead.

```
for i=1:size(X,1)
    for j=1:size(X,2)
    res(i,j)=fun([X(i,j),Y(i,j)])
    end
end
```

What are you trying to do?

Also, in Matlab, you should use `%` instead of `//` for commenting

These are some related questions:

[arrayfun when each row of the array is an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199666/arrayfun-when-each-row-of-the-array-is-an-input)

[Passing a vector as multiple inputs to a function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/374337-passing-a-vector-as-multiple-inputs-to-a-function)

Comment: @ Amin: I would like to avoid two nested loops for and make the code clearer. In general, this approach is significantly faster for large data than using for loops.

Comment: @justik: `arrayfun` is a for loop. Why do you say it is significantly faster than a for loop?

Comment: @ Cris: You are right, there is no measurable speed increment, I tried it out. And confirmed here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/324130-is-arrayfun-faster-much-more-than-for-loop