# Z-scores using specified mu and sigma

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, normalization, scaling

I have converted my training data matrix into [*z*-scores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) for each column. I have `mu` and `sigma` for each column from the output of [`zscore`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/zscore.html).

I also have another matrix (my test data) and I want to convert it into *z*-scores using the `mu` and `sigma` obtained in previous the step. My implementation uses `for` loops as shown below:

```
TEST_DATA = zeros(num_rows,num_cols,'double');

for rowIdx = 1:num_rows,
    for colIdx = 1:num_cols,
        TEST_DATA(rowIdx,colIdx)=(input(rowIdx,colIdx)-MU(colIdx))/SIGMA(colIdx);
    end
end
```

Is there any faster way of achieving this in MATLAB?

Comment: Be more specific.  Explain what a z-score is, and explain what operation you want to do to your data.

Comment: @Peter please see edited OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
%// Sample data
matrix = rand(10, 10);
testData = rand(10, 10); 

%// Obtain mu and sigma
mu = mean(matrix, 1);
sigma = std(matrix, [], 1);
%// or use: [Z, mu, sigma] = zscore(matrix);

%// Convert into z-scores using precalculated mu and sigma
C = bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, testData, mu), sigma);
```

Comment: +1: Instead of `@times` and `1 ./ sigma`, you could use `@rdivide` and `sigma`.

Comment: @H.Muster Correct me if I am wrong... The `bsxfun` runs on all elements of matrix (rows * cols) and can be used to replace 2 for-loops as in my example code in OP?

Comment: @EitanT: Thanks for reminding me. I mostly use `@times` because I always forget whether `@rdivide` or `@ldivide` is necessary. And thanks for adding comments and links.

Comment: @KhurramMajeed: yes, each `bsxfun` replaces one loop, but they do not run on the individual elements, but on each row of testData, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @H.Muster You are correct indeed. Here's a related question: [Is bsxfun really applied element-wise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18079629/1336150)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of zscore explains that it simply subtracts the mean and divides by the standard deviation.  The only tricky part is apply the vectors of mu/sigma to each column.  But if you don't know how to do the fancy way, do it with a for loop.  I'll leave it this way for readability.  If you need faster, look into `bsxfun`.

```
for ii=1:size(mat,1)
    mat(ii,:) = (mat(ii,:) - mu) ./ sigma;
end
```